Maxwell's Equations Expressed via Potentials with the Inclusion of Magnetic Monopoles
I am currently facing difficulties in establishing a rigorous proof of the following expression:
\begin{equation} E = -\nabla \phi_e - \partial_t A_e -\frac{1}{\varepsilon_0} \nabla \times A_m. \end{equation}
I have an approach in mind that draws parallels to the classical derivation of the potentials in the absence of magnetic monopoles
\begin{equation}
\nabla \cdot B = 0 \implies B = \nabla \times A_e,
\end{equation}
but I am uncertain about how to proceed with it. Would you be able to offer any guidance or suggest relevant literature that could assist me in this matter?
